# Degree to which Outlook Online supports search phrase syntax

Tags: search, outlook-web-access

I'm very clumsy at using GUIs, so I try to avoid the Outlook Advanced Search GUI.  I recently found the following salvations:

- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/learn-to-narrow-your-search-criteria-for-better-searches-in-outlook-d824d1e9-a255-4c8a-8553-276fb895a8da
- https://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/searchcommands.htm

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work with "Outlook Online".  I hope used the right term.  It is web access to Outlook on Office 365, which I thought was called OWA, but now I suspect it is Outlook Online.

Anyway, I have a message in folder InboxNot containing the word "Mandatory".  It is not found, however, with the following search phrase:

```
Mandatory folderpath:InboxNot
```

Is there an authoritative document on the search syntax for Outlook Online versus Outlook desktop application?

**Afternote:**  I found this from the OWA help facility:

- https://support.office.com/en-ca/f1/topic/search-mail-and-people-in-outlook-on-the-web-b27e5eb7-3255-4c61-bf16-1c6a16bc2e6b?NS=OLWAO365B&Version=16

Scarily, it seems very limiting.  I hope it is not the full story.  Hoping that there is more to this....

Comment: I found some more and some of these seem to work even though my email is not part of exchange.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/keyword-queries-and-search-conditions?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fKeyword-queries-and-search-conditions-for-Content-Search-c4639c2e-7223-4302-8e0d-b6e10f1c3be3&view=o365-worldwide

Comment: Interesting.  On one hand, I hope to find documentatoin of capabilities beyond the limited options from the OWA help.  On the other hand, I fear the proliferation of variations of supported syntax for different variations of the Outlook platform, which could consume a lot of time (the very thing I'm hoping to avoid by nailing down the boundaries of what is supported by OWA search).  What a mess.